# Angular2 nesting components with interpolation

Tags: angular, typescript, interpolation, angular2-directives

I am learning Angular2 from scratch, trying to figure out how to pass the name of the component to be load through a variable rather than a static call. I tried using interpolation as below but I can't get it to work.

As per example:
survey.component is actually a component that just displays "hello world".

If you look at the template in the component decorator there are 2 lines which pretty much hold the same value, just one is passed with interpolation and the other is a static call.

The static line displays "Hello world", while the value interpolated pastes directly the string "< survey >< survey >" instead of the content of the "Hello world".

How would I nest a component inside a component with a variable?

I tried google, but all I can find is topics regarding communication between the 2 components not using interpolation to insert a component inside a component. Hope my question is not "to stupid".

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {SurveyComponent} from './survey.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'rpane',
    template: `{{ componentLoad }}
               <survey></survey>
              `,
    directives: [SurveyComponent]
})

export class RPaneComponent {
    componentLoad = '<survey></survey>';
}
```

Comment: Interpolation will always transform it to string

Comment: So how to do it the proper way?

Comment: Use dynamic loading. See this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-component-with-angular2